# Admob real ads not showing after publishing it

Tags: android, admob, ads

After I publish my game in google play and download from play store, I'am waiting for my banner ads to come up and unfortunately it doesn't showing up... but when I include the build.adTest(); when I trying the game/app the ads shows. What do you think is the problem or do admob take some time to show their live/real ads?

Comment: Can you please add your code

Comment: @ApurvaKolapkar My game is now published on google play. I don't include the adTestDevice("xxxx.."); ... but when I debugging/ testing the game with adTestDevice();, the ads shows up.

Answer (score 17):

According to Google

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and
>   requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start
>   getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads
>   then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you
>   are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID
>   for us to look into."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo

so wait for a few hours.

Comment: its been 6 Days since no ad is showing

Comment: Any update with this? Did you just have to wait or did you implement it wrong? @AmanDeep

Comment: @frankied003 it started working after 10 Days :)

Comment: 10 days? That's crazy! I have to wait for a week more. :(

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I have to submit the payment details first to show ads in app. Just visit admob and read the warning at top.

Comment: Checkout this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143111/unable-to-setup-payment-method-on-new-admob-account.

Comment: In the payment section it is saying : The requested URL was not found on this server!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue
spent 1/2 days of analysis
because of an innocent looking/clever bug:

It was due to 2 things mainly:

1. I removed all default test ids from all plugins
   this helped me to know what is the issue
   we know different types of ads will have different default test ids given in AdMob
   .
   troubleshooting I did is below:

   - a) test ad id - test ad should load
   - b) wrong ad id - no ad should on load (nothing should show), wrong id can be '1111111'
   - c) real ad id - real ad should NOT load locally (nothing should show, since it not uploaded)
   - d) real ad id - real ad should load after uploading to google play (after 4 hours or so, after upload)
2. using above point, I fixed the bug in the code
   innocent looking copied code from the internet worked great for test ads
   since it loaded test ads correctly, have assumed it was correct code as other said both test & real ads are from same channel (real ads won't show until uploaded to play console, acc. to point d) above)

when the ad id was given incorrect, a plugin was taking default test id so showing test ads

just before uploading apk to play console, changed to real id, built and released apk

after uploading to play store, initially showed a blank screen for a few hours (maybe 2-4 hours), then real ads started showing.

hope that was detailed & helps others, else ping below.

Comment: I have not uploaded my app on play store yet. So you are saying that is the reason for real ads not showing up??

Comment: Looks like so, for initial/first-time upload.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I tried 2-3 days.
I had placed the correct ad id, but ads were not showing in real device.
I got this problem fixed by :

1. I published the app on play store.
2. I shared the app to 3-4 friends to test it. Even then the ads were not shown, after 2-3 hours ads began to show.

Conclusion: For newly created ads to work, Admob need more requests to start showing ads.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Sometimes it takes some time. And, it also depends on your geographic location. Some locations have more ads availability than others.