# admob ads are not working in signed apk,it worked perfect at debugging version

Tags: android, admob

AdMob ads are not working in signed apk, it worked perfectly at debugging version. Why does the signed apk not showing ads?
Please help me to find out this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admob real ads not showing after publishing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783990/admob-real-ads-not-showing-after-publishing-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ads display automatically when the app was published