# Google AdMob returns "Configuration does not have valid Google App ID"

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, admob

It's been almost a week since my app went Live, but my live Google ads are not showing at all.

I've tried double checking everything I could think of, such as making sure the App ID and Ad ID are correct, but I'm having no luck with them.

I have the following 2 functions to load and show the ads

```
public func loadAd() {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3228561607874346/1546949023") //Live Ad 2
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)
}

public func showAd() {
    
    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        
        loadAd()
        
    } else {
      print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}
```

I tried running it with test ads using the test ad ID that were given to me on Google's tutorial page and that seems to be working fine, just not my Live Ad.

The only thing that flags or catch my attention is the console is printing:

> [I-ACS023136] Configuration does not have valid Google App ID.

and

> [I-ACS034010] Transaction failed

But like I said, I double checked my config in my info.plist file and all seems to be fine.

There are over 200 requests made and 0% match-rate. I just don't know what it could be.

Comment: this error doesn't look like of admob. Do you have crashlytics within your project? Admob error will be displayed with codes mentioned in this link https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Did you add GADApplicationIdentifier and SKAdNetworkIdentifier as described in https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some research and most people solved their issues related to AdMob by waiting a few days. Since your app went live more than a week ago, I believe that's not the issue. Another possible solution is to share your app with more people, in order to send more requests to Google Servers. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644530/11578778) answer:

> For newly created ads to work, Admob need more requests to start showing ads.

Also:

- Make sure that Google Mobile Ads SDK is properly integrated.
- Make sure that you are using the Real ID because sometimes the Test ID is used by default.
- Make sure there are no restrictions on your account.
- Make sure that the account setup is fully completed. Payment information, name, address, phone number, and tax info in your AdMob account with verification if applicable.
- Check that the eCPM floor settings are not set too high.

An unlikely but possible reason could be *lack of inventory*.

If none of the above worked, you can try these troubleshooters:

[Performance Troubleshoot](https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/3264078) - [Can't see ADS Troubleshoot](https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685)

More info:

[Common reasons for ads not showing](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads the interstitial ad inside the if condition.
Call your load before you check if it is ready.

interstitial.isReady indicates that the ad is fully loaded.
You can see this website for more information: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial.

It is also better practice to call loadAd function in viewDidLoad and display it when needed.

I also recommend using the test id for Google Admob.
It is listed in the url: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

Don't forget to include Admob App Id in GoogleService-Info.plist. I think it is included automatically, but you can check it.