# Failed to read publisher's account configuration; please check your configured app ID. Received app ID: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713`

Tags: android, sdk, admob

You guys have any idea as to what may be the possible cause of this error in **UMP SDK** for **Android**?

**Publisher misconfiguration: Failed to read publisher's account configuration; please check your configured app ID. Received app ID: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713`.**

*ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713* is Test Application ID

and this Error Pops up when trying to use **Obtaining Consent with the User Messaging Platform**

I followed the procedure  as outlined in https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/ump/android/quick-start

I do not get an option to create / view Funding Choices account, but still this is a test application id.

```
public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError)
{
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution just in case, maybe he got the idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810223/7110147

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this error by logging into Admob and configuring my GDPR and IDFA messages here: https://apps.admob.com/v2/privacymessaging

After I configured and allowed those messages the error went away, and it worked even while displaying test ads on an emulator.

Comment: this should be the correct answer :D. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar case and the solution is simple. You're using the sample AdMob ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 and thats the case.

It's good enough to displays test ads but not to set user's consent and it end up with an error. You are actually trying to send the request in AdMob test account what is not allowed.

For UMP to works, you need to create a real (your own) AdMob account and use its AdMob ID. If you still need to run test ads, just set the test device ID https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433?hl=en