# AdMob Diagnosing Banner Not Displaying

Tags: ios, flutter, admob

I have an app in iOS TestFlight. It has AdMob ads. I originally deployed the app with the demo unit id and the app showed demo ads. So far, so good. I got my AdMob account approved and I added the real unit ID to my app as per the instructions. I ran the app on the simulator and the banner shows up, albeit with demo ads. So, I deployed this version to TestFlight, and now the app in TestFlight doesn't show any banner.

I don't know what is going wrong. It should at least display the demo banner. I would have to add some kind of logging to diagnose the issue.

So, I checked the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10159602) and [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9388275).

I added my physical iPhone as a Test Device in the AdMob console, but my device still doesn't display any ads and the shake gesture does nothing.

The documentation says that I need to have the app in the store before I can serve ads, but it's a chicken-and-egg scenario. I want to make sure the ads are working before I deploy them to the store. I would at least like the demo banner to display, but even that won't display right now.

I also followed [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/test-ads#add_your_test_device_programmatically). If I add this test Swift code, the banner shows up. But this doesn't really help me much because it requires that I put the specific device id into the app.

```swift
GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = [ "[DEVICE ID]" ]
```

My two options are to roll back to the demo ad unit id which displays the incorrect demo banner or just hope for the best. Can anyone recommend advice here, or at least explain how I can get the ads to display on the test device?

**Edit: The app works fine with the demo advert but it got rejected from the Apple store because the ad says "Test". It's a chicken and egg scenario.**

Comment: Please check app readiness status in order to view live advert. If your app works correctly with demo advert then it will work correctly with live ads https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477

Comment: It does work correctly with the demo add.

Comment: It does take time to get real time advertisements ( also location of advertisment , category of app etc also matters). Check from admob console for fill rate column after all checklist with app readiness is complete

Answer (score 0):

> verify all below points
>
> 1. First visit admob console and read the warning at top. add payments information if not added and approve your account.
> 2. Verify once, you **replaced** your production `ads IDs` properly in your `app code` for `production environment`.
> 3. For production Advertising your app need to add for **review** first from **admob console** too. checkout this [documentation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477?hl=en).
> 4. **app-ads-txt** correctly updated with status or not. checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423387/what-is-app-ads-txt-and-how-do-i-implement-it-in-admob/71005021#71005021)
> 5. If your Ads working in development environment Ads will work for production too if above all steps correctly done. some times on
>    New production ad IDs takes `few hours or requests to load` ads in user's
>    device. checkout below links
>
> - **Common reasons for ads not showing** - [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en)
> - Take time too load production ads - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783990/admob-real-ads-not-showing-after-publishing-it)

For iOS TestFlight app rejection, `your app contains any test keywords (test, lorem ipsum...) in app store listing content (screenshots or app contains testing data)`. for resolve this go-through [app store review guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477?hl=en).